# Sending emails with WAMP

Tags: php, email

I use the latest WAMP and I get this when I try to send emails:

```
Warning: mail() [function.mail]: Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\wamp\www\main\createaccount.php on line 8
```

Message delivery failed...

The message:

```
$to = "xxx@hotmail.com";
$subject = "Hi!";
$body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";
if (mail($to, $subject, $body)) {
  echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
 } else {
  echo("<p>Message delivery failed...</p>");
 }
```

Do you need do download a "mailserver" also?

Please help.

Answer (score 15):

This works for me and should work for you: Use [Fake Sendmail](http://glob.com.au/sendmail/) and a webhost mail server (i.e. - Godaddy, 1and1, etc.).

1.) Download the sendmail zip and extract it to C:\Wamp\bin\sendmail (for purposes of this example).

2.) Edit C:\wamp\bin\sendmail\sendmail.ini and set the following to your mail server's requirements (mine are below):

```
smtp_server=mail.yourdomain.com
smtp_port=26
smtp_ssl=none
;default_domain=yourdomain.com
auth_username=smtpuser@yourdomain.com
auth_password=smtppassword
;pop3_server=
;pop3_username=
;pop3_password=
;force_sender=
;force_recipient=
```

3.) Set the path of sendmail.exe in your php.ini file.

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
SMTP =

; For Win32 only.
sendmail_from =

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
sendmail_path = "C:\wamp\bin\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t"
```

4.) Restart Wampserver.

You might have success using Gmail, but there are a few extra tweaks to make it work.  I prefer using the mail server of the webhost where I upload my code.

Comment: Exactly what I needed to link my dev. environment with the actual GoDaddy account. Much appreciated !

Comment: THIS WORKS! Thank you. This saved me. All the sudden Wamp64 server stops working on development localhost and this saved me.

Comment: Thx for this, in my case I had to add the SMTP & smtp_port also in the php.ini. Using Apache 2.4.9 (Win32) PHP 7.2.3

Answer (score 1):

You are not running an smtp server on your machine, but you don't have to. Just set SMTP to a open smtp server for example:

```
ini_set('SMTP', 'smtp.yourisp.com');
```

Take a look at your ISP's home page or http://www.e-eeasy.com/SMTPServerList.aspx for list of SMTP servers.

If you have a desktop mail program, you can use the same address as you use for outgoing mail.

Comment: thanksman, tried many server not but i get the same error message, maybe some other program i run use port 25 ;/

Comment: Are sure you are putting the `ini_set` before the `mail` function and have you tried your own ISP's SMTP server?

Answer (score 0):

I think your mail server (SMTP) outgoing mail server is not configured in your php.ini file.

Have a look at this:

http://email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/Configure_PHP_to_Use_a_Remote_SMTP_Server_for_Sending_Mail.htm

Also hotmail doesn't allow you to use their mailservers.  You should use yahoo or gmail.

Comment: At least Gmail requires SSL protected connection, so that's not an option with plain old `mail()`.

Comment: @Tatu Ulmanen: Thanks :) I don't think yahoo does, from what I recall.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure these servers have a mail program installed on them? If not, that's your problem. For example, XAMPP comes with a mail program called Mercury which you must start before you can send mail through the server.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this article, it works if you have a gmail account.
or at least any email account in which you know the server, port and this stuff.

[Send Email From localhost](http://blog.techwheels.net/send-email-from-localhost-wamp-server-using-sendmail/)

Answer (score 0):

## here is another solution - [WAMP send Mail using SMTP localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830673/wamp-send-mail-using-smtp-localhost)

KEEP IN MIND, everytime, after You change php.ini,

## you must restart wamp (! ! !)

p.s. in php.ini, i have used:

```
SMTP = localhost 
smtp_port = 25 
sendmail_from = your_user@gmail.com
```

or if oyu cant edit php.ini, try to insert these lines in your php script.

```
ini_set("SMTP", "localhost");
ini_set("smtp_port", "25");
ini_set("sendmail_from", "your_user@gmail.com");
```