# how to test php email using WAMP

Tags: php, wamp

I have wamp installed and am using it as my testing ground. I can't however test the PHP `mail()` function as it always falls over.

Is this something that can be rectified?

exact message:

```
Warning:  mail() [<a href='function.mail'>function.mail</a>]: Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\wamp\www\functions.php on line 288
```

I've also checked my php.ini setup and it looks as follows:

```
 [mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = technical@clevermutt.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
;sendmail_path =

; Force the addition of the specified parameters to be passed as extra parameters
; to the sendmail binary. These parameters will always replace the value of
; the 5th parameter to mail(), even in safe mode.
;mail.force_extra_parameters =

; Add X-PHP-Originating-Script: that will include uid of the script followed by the filename
mail.add_x_header = On

; Log all mail() calls including the full path of the script, line #, to address and headers
;mail.log =
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you be more specific? Are you receiving any errors when you use `mail()`? "it always falls over" isn't useful to us programmers.

Comment: apologies, I was being lazy. updated with more info above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.sourceforge.net) to point to an external SMTP server. Or you could use a simple [script that dumps to a file](http://www.drupal4hu.com/node/55). There are a [couple of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600725/how-to-configure-wamp-localhost-to-send-email-using-gmail) [earlier questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993070/sending-emails-with-wamp) on the same topic, with more ideas.

Answer (score 2):

you have to modify your PHP.ini file settings to include an SMTP server, port and sendmail_from

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25
```

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = you@yourdomain

Answer (score 0):

install free argosoft mail [argosoft](http://www.argosoft.com/rootpages/MailServerNET/Default.aspx) and try whatever you want with mail in php

Comment: ...I think my head's ready to explode after a quick look at that page! I have to admit, servers are my weak point. I'm using WAMP because it was quite painless to set up on my laptop without having to understand the ins and outs. This looks quite complex to do, or am I misreading it?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Gmail as SMTP server, that will work anywhere, on any server, any OS. If you use a Google Apps email account, you can even use your own custom From: email-address.

Links:

Example PHP code:  http://deepakssn.blogspot.com/2006/06/gmail-php-send-email-using-php-with.html

Google Apps: http://www.google.com/apps/