# (WAMP/XAMP) send Mail using SMTP localhost

Tags: smtp

How to send mail from localhost SMTP (using Wamp,Xampp or etc..)? PHP `mail()` doesn't seem to work natively.

Can anybody give the instructions?

Comment: With xampp or wampp you need to configure mercury for sending mails from localhost. Are you asking for the configuration?

Comment: The techwheels's one works for me! `:)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this library to send email ,if having issue with local xampp,wamp...

> class.phpmailer.php,class.smtp.php
>   Write this code in file where your email function calls

```
    include('class.phpmailer.php');

    $mail = new PHPMailer();  
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    $mail->Port = 465;
    $mail->Username = "your email ID";
    $mail->Password = "your email password";
    $fromname = "From Name in Email";

$To = trim($email,"\r\n");
      $tContent   = '';

      $tContent .="<table width='550px' colspan='2' cellpadding='4'>
            <tr><td align='center'><img src='imgpath' width='100' height='100'></td></tr>
            <tr><td height='20'>&nbsp;</td></tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <table cellspacing='1' cellpadding='1' width='100%' height='100%'>
                <tr><td align='center'><h2>YOUR TEXT<h2></td></tr/>
                <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
                <tr><td align='center'>Name: ".trim(NAME,"\r\n")."</td></tr>
                <tr><td align='center'>ABCD TEXT: ".$abcd."</td></tr>
                <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>                
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
            </table>";
      $mail->From = "From email";
      $mail->FromName = $fromname;        
      $mail->Subject = "Your Details."; 
      $mail->Body = $tContent;
      $mail->AddAddress($To); 
      $mail->set('X-Priority', '1'); //Priority 1 = High, 3 = Normal, 5 = low
      $mail->Send();
```

Answer (score 38):

## Method 1 (Preferred)  - Using **[hMailServer](https://www.hmailserver.com/download)**

After installation, you need the following configuration to properly send mail from wampserver:

```
1) When you first open hMailServer Administrator, you need to add a new domain.
2) Click on the "Add Domain ..." button at the Welcome page. 
3) Under the domain text field, enter your computer's IP, in this case it should be 127.0.0.1.
4) Click on the Save button.
5) Go to Settings>Protocols>SMTP and select "Delivery of Email" tab
6) Enter "localhost" in the localhost name field.
7) Click on the Save button.
```

If you need to send mail using a FROM addressee of another computer, you need to allow deliveries from External to External accounts. To do that, follow these steps:

```
1) Go to Settings>Advanced>IP Ranges and double click on "My Computer" which should have IP address of 127.0.0.1
2) Check the Allow Deliveries from External to External accounts checkbox.
3) Save settings using Save button.
```

(However, Windows Live/Hotmail has denied all emails coming from dynamic IPs, which most residential computers are using. The workaround is to use Gmail account )

## Note to use Gmail users :

```
1) Go to Settings>Protocols>SMTP and select "Delivery of Email" tab
2) Enter "smtp.gmail.com" in the Remote Host name field.
3) Enter "465" as the port number
4) Check "Server requires authentication"
5) Enter gmail address in the Username
6) Enter gmail password in the password 
7) Check "Use SSL"
```

*(Note, **From** field doesnt function with gmail)*

*p.s. For some people it might also be needed to untick everything under `require SMTP authentication` in :

- **for local    :** Settings>Advanced>IP Ranges>"My Computer"
- **for external :** Settings>Advanced>IP Ranges>"Internet"

---

## Method 2  - Using SendMail

You can use [SendMail installation](http://blog.techwheels.net/send-email-from-localhost-wamp-server-using-sendmail/).

---

## Method 3  - Using different methods

Use any of [these methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773288/configure-wamp-server-to-send-email).

Comment: Great answer and works. Just to add to that, I needed under advanced -> ip ranges -> my computer , to untick everything under 'require SMTP authentication' since php mail() has none available.

Answer (score 5):

**Here's the steps to achieve this:**

- Download the sendmail.zip through this [link](http://www.glob.com.au/sendmail/sendmail.zip)

  - Now, extract the folder and put it to C:/wamp/. Make sure that these four files are present: sendmail.exe, libeay32.dll, ssleay32.ddl and sendmail.ini.
  - Open sendmail.ini and set the configuration as follows:
  - smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
  - smtp_port=465
  - smtp_ssl=ssl
  - default_domain=localhost
  - error_logfile=error.log
  - debug_logfile=debug.log
  - auth_username=[your_gmail_account_username]@gmail.com
  - auth_password=[your_gmail_account_password]
  - pop3_server=
  - pop3_username=
  - pop3_password=
  - force_sender=
  - force_recipient=
  - hostname=localhost
  - Access your email account. Click the Gear Tool > Settings > Forwarding and POP/IMAP > IMAP access. Click "Enable IMAP", then save your changes.
  - Run your WAMP Server. Enable ssl_module under Apache Module.
  - Next, enable php_openssl and php_sockets under PHP.
  - Open php.ini and configure it as the codes below. Basically, you just have to set the sendmail_path.

> ```
> [mail function]
> ; For Win32 only.
> ; http://php.net/smtp
> ;SMTP =
> ; http://php.net/smtp-port
> ;smtp_port = 25
>
> ; For Win32 only.
> ; http://php.net/sendmail-from
> ;sendmail_from = you@domain.com
> ; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
> ; http://php.net/sendmail-path
> sendmail_path = "C:\wamp\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t -i"
> ```

- Restart Wamp Server

I hope this will work for you..

Comment: I followed all your steps, but wamp server stopped running after enable - ssl_module in Apache.

Comment: When you say: "Access your email account", are you talking about my personal gmail account (wondering what does it have to do with all this) or it's some kind of another account???

Answer (score 2):

you can directly send mail from php mail() function if you specified the smtp server and smtp port in php.ini, first ask the **SMTP server credential** to your ISP.

```
SMTP = smtp.wlink.com.np //put your ISP's smtp server

smtp_port = 25 // your ISP's smtp port.
```

then just restart the apache server and it will start working. ENjoy ...

Answer (score 0):

If any one of you are getting error like following after following answer given by **Afwe Wef**

```
 Warning: mail() [<a href='function.mail'>function.mail</a>]: SMTP server response:

 550 The address is not valid. in c:\wamp\www\email.php
```

Go to *php.ini*

```
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = valideaccount@gmail.com
```

Enter valideaccount@gmail.com as your email id which you used to configure the hMailserver in front of *sendmail_from* .

your problem will be solved.

Tested on Wamp server2.2(Apache 2.2.22, php 5.3.13) on windows 8

If you are also getting following error

```
"APPLICATION"   6364    "2014-03-24 13:13:33.979"   "SMTPDeliverer - Message 2: Relaying to host smtp.gmail.com."
"APPLICATION"   6364    "2014-03-24 13:13:34.415"   "SMTPDeliverer - Message 2: Message could not be delivered. Scheduling it for later delivery in 60 minutes."
"APPLICATION"   6364    "2014-03-24 13:13:34.430"   "SMTPDeliverer - Message 2: Message delivery thread completed."
```

You might have forgot to change the port from 25 to 465

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using PHPMailer script to send emails from localhost as it lets me use my Gmail account as SMTP. You can find the PHPMailer from http://phpmailer.worxware.com/ . Help regarding how to use gmail as SMTP or any other SMTP can be found at http://www.mittalpatel.co.in/php_send_mail_from_localhost_using_gmail_smtp . Hope this helps!