# SMTP Bcc mail not working

Tags: php, email, smtp

Here is a simple code to send a SMTP mail to send mail via user authentication. The code works fine for To: but Bcc: does not work. When we use normal php mail() function we include the Bcc: to the header. But I am not sure how to use Bcc: here using SMTP protocol.

```
$SmtpServer="127.0.0.1";
$SmtpPort="25"; //default
$SmtpUser="username";
$SmtpPass="password";

class SMTPClient
{

function SMTPClient ($SmtpServer, $SmtpPort, $SmtpUser, $SmtpPass, $from, $to, $subject, $body, $bcc)
{

$this->SmtpServer = $SmtpServer;
$this->SmtpUser = base64_encode ($SmtpUser);
$this->SmtpPass = base64_encode ($SmtpPass);
$this->from = $from;
$this->to = $to;
$this->subject = $subject;
$this->body = $body;

if ($SmtpPort == "")
{
$this->PortSMTP = 25;
}
else
{
$this->PortSMTP = $SmtpPort;
}
}

function SendMail ()
{
if ($SMTPIN = fsockopen ($this->SmtpServer, $this->PortSMTP))
{
fputs ($SMTPIN, "EHLO ".$HTTP_HOST."\r\n");
$talk["hello"] = fgets ( $SMTPIN, 1024 );
fputs($SMTPIN, "auth login\r\n");
$talk["res"]=fgets($SMTPIN,1024);
fputs($SMTPIN, $this->SmtpUser."\r\n");
$talk["user"]=fgets($SMTPIN,1024);
fputs($SMTPIN, $this->SmtpPass."\r\n");
$talk["pass"]=fgets($SMTPIN,256);
fputs ($SMTPIN, "MAIL FROM: <".$this->from.">\r\n");
$talk["From"] = fgets ( $SMTPIN, 1024 );
fputs ($SMTPIN, "RCPT TO: <".$this->to.">\r\n");
$talk["To"] = fgets ($SMTPIN, 1024);
fputs($SMTPIN, "DATA\r\n");
$talk["data"]=fgets( $SMTPIN,1024 );
fputs($SMTPIN, "To: <".$this->to.">\r\nBcc: ".$bcc."\r\nFrom: <".$this->from.">\r\nSubject:".$this->subject."\r\n\r\n\r\n".$this->body."\r\n.\r\n");
$talk["send"]=fgets($SMTPIN,256);
//CLOSE CONNECTION AND EXIT ...
fputs ($SMTPIN, "QUIT\r\n");
fclose($SMTPIN);
//
}
return $talk;
}
}

$to = 'abc@abc.com';
$from = 'xyz@xyz.com';
$subject = 'test subject';
$body = 'body';
$bcc = 'aaa@aaa.com, bbb@bbb.com, ccc@.com';
$SMTPMail = new SMTPClient ($SmtpServer, $SmtpPort, $SmtpUser, $SmtpPass, $from, $to, $subject, $body, $bcc);
$SMTPChat = $SMTPMail->SendMail();
```

Above code

Comment: did you check this one before? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830673/wamp-send-mail-using-smtp-localhost

Comment: Try using the PHPMailer library: https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer

Answer (score 0):

Put bcc adresses in their own "RCPT TO:" SMTP commands, remove Bcc: header.

Anyway not cheking SMTP reply codes is a recipe for trouble for ham (not spam) senders.