# Joomla password reset not working

Tags: php, email, joomla, localhost, reset-password

Dear joomla experts I'm facing a issue . In front page of my site there is Log_in Box under which two link is given create account and forgot password. My site running on a local host means on local server. 
when a user click on forgot password he/she will redirect to page where it is asked to enter it's email address. When a user enter his mail id then click submit then next page says "Notice SMTP connect failed"
and another message is "Please check your email and follow the instructions to reset your password"
But no mail is send to that address 
Can any one help me out for this problem.
Why it showing SMTP fail and why not sending mail

By surfing on net I do lots of changes in global configuration still not able to over come this problem .

Please help .Please tell me the whole procedure is there any module , component which help me

please help me experts

Answer (score 0):

You are using the localhost. That is the reason for failed in sending emails. That is you needt o configure SMTP settings on your system then only you can send mails .[To set SMTP protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830673/wamp-send-mail-using-smtp-localhost) please visit this link

Answer (score 0):

You have to run a mailserver on your localhost. XAMPP, for example has Mercury for this. You have to configure this to run so that you are able to recieve and send mails. After that you you have to go to joomlas global konfiguration and add the connection data.

But why you do this on a local maschine? do you want to reset the admin account? if so do it in the database - much easier ;)