# php mail function Failed to connect to mail server at

Tags: php, email

i will send mail using php mail function but it can display some error..

> Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mail server at
>        "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and
>        "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in

mail.php

```
    <?PHP
    $sender = 'sender123@gmail.com';
    $recipient = 'resever123@gmail.com';

    $subject = "php mail test";
    $message = "php test message";
    $headers = 'From:' . $sender;

    if (mail($recipient, $subject, $message, $headers))
    {
        echo "Message accepted";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Error: Message not accepted";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Have you got a mailserver set up on your local machine? It doesn't sound like it..

Answer (score 1):

If you are testing on your localhost you most likely dont have an SMTP setup.  You have to setup an smtp connection for php to send the message.

I would suggest using something like phpmailer which makes it easier when working on local testing servers.

Comment: how i have setup smtp in my locallhost help me to do.

Comment: what software did you use when installing the server

Comment: WAMP server php version is 7.1.16

Comment: The following post goes over all the details you need https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830673/wamp-send-mail-using-smtp-localhost