# How to Fix Email script with a PHP error, and I'm unsure as to whether it is an issue of WAMP Server?

Tags: php, html, email

I am trying to build a simple Contact Form on Dreamweaver that will email user responses to a designated email.

However, I am getting the above problem: Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set()

I have 2 PHP based files on dreamweaver:

1. mailscript
2. contactform

   Untitled Document

   Text Field:
                     
            
         
         
            
         
         
           Text Area:
           
         
         
            
         
         
           
         
         
            
         
       
     
     Content for form Goes Here

Comment: Please refer this solution for sending mails form wamp - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830673/wamp-xamp-send-mail-using-smtp-localhost

Comment: Possible duplicate of [(WAMP/XAMP) send Mail using SMTP localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830673/wamp-xamp-send-mail-using-smtp-localhost)