# Sending an email with wamp

Tags: php, email, wamp, wamp64

After more than 1 day of research on the configuration of the php.ini and sendmail.ini files I cannot get my mail function to work , This is where I am currently on a test.php file.

test.php

```
<?php
$to = "mymail@gmail.com";
$subject = "Utilisation de mail()";
$message = "Salut, comment ça va";

$headers =  'From: mymail@gmail.com'. "\r\n" .
            'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
            'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8';
           

if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)){
    echo 'Envoye !';
}else{    echo 'Erreur envoi';}
```

php.ini v8.2

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; https://php.net/smtp
SMTP = 
; https://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; https://php.net/sendmail-from
;sendmail_from ="admin@wampserver.invalid"

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; https://php.net/sendmail-path
sendmail_path = "C:/wamp64/bin/sendmail/sendmail.exe -t"

; Force the addition of the specified parameters to be passed as extra parameters
; to the sendmail binary. These parameters will always replace the value of
; the 5th parameter to mail().
;mail.force_extra_parameters =

; Add X-PHP-Originating-Script: that will include uid of the script followed by the filename
mail.add_x_header = Off

; Use mixed LF and CRLF line separators to keep compatibility with some
; RFC 2822 non conformant MTA.
mail.mixed_lf_and_crlf = Off

; The path to a log file that will log all mail() calls. Log entries include
; the full path of the script, line number, To address and headers.
;mail.log =
; Log mail to syslog (Event Log on Windows).
;mail.log = syslog
```

sendmail.ini

```
[sendmail]

; you must change mail.mydomain.com to your smtp server,
; or to IIS's "pickup" directory.  (generally C:\Inetpub\mailroot\Pickup)
; emails delivered via IIS's pickup directory cause sendmail to
; run quicker, but you won't get error messages back to the calling
; application.

smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com

; smtp port (normally 25)

smtp_port=465

; SMTPS (SSL) support
;   auto = use SSL for port 465, otherwise try to use TLS
;   ssl  = alway use SSL
;   tls  = always use TLS
;   none = never try to use SSL

smtp_ssl=ssl

; the default domain for this server will be read from the registry
; this will be appended to email addresses when one isn't provided
; if you want to override the value in the registry, uncomment and modify

default_domain=localhost

; log smtp errors to error.log (defaults to same directory as sendmail.exe)
; uncomment to enable logging

error_logfile=error.log

; create debug log as debug.log (defaults to same directory as sendmail.exe)
; uncomment to enable debugging

debug_logfile=debug.log

; if your smtp server requires authentication, modify the following two lines

auth_username=mymail@gmail.com
auth_password=(Google PIN)


; if your smtp server uses pop3 before smtp authentication, modify the 
; following three lines.  do not enable unless it is required.

pop3_server=
pop3_username=
pop3_password=

; force the sender to always be the following email address
; this will only affect the "MAIL FROM" command, it won't modify 
; the "From: " header of the message content

force_sender=mymail@gmail.com
```

I know there are a lot of open topics but no solution works to get rid of this error: Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\wamp64\www\test-mail.php

Comment: Did you enable SMTP service in your machine (localhost) ?

Comment: how does it “enable”? I downloaded the sendmail package and unzipped the folder into my bin folder

Comment: It appears that your machine is windows OS , if it is Windows server then it is enabled usually, but if it is Windows client (e.g. Win 10/ 11, then you need to do something to enable SMTP)

Comment: You may refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830673/wamp-xamp-send-mail-using-smtp-localhost) for further information too.

Comment: ok I used hMailServer and once configured I have a new error which is: Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 530 SMTP authentication is required. Do you know where this could come from since I have already entered my Google account information?

Comment: You will probably run into many problems as it relates to email, just a warning. I would recommend reading this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24644450/231316) which covers many of them. Even after you are able to _send_, you might not _receive_ the message. And if you are developing local with a plan to move to a production server you might have to re-do everything you've done. I say all of this to not discourage you, just to warn you. Although email _should_ be simple, the fact that it was simple is why spam and phishing are so easy, and there are many defenses in place these days.

Comment: I developped a mailer using java code and basic authentication is not working at all... I had to implement OAuth2 ... You should consider reading the following: https://mailtrap.io/blog/phpmailer-gmail/